# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 1.090393000000000E+00, -2.059937000000000E-01'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

when I apply the following command in my code:

```
s11polar = np.array(ena.query_ascii_values(cmdDict['s11']+cmdDict['polar']+';'+cmdDict['numGroups']+str(numGrps)+';outpform'))
```

The following error is shown up:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '   1.090393000000000E+00,  -2.059937000000000E-01'
```

This time I added a separator as follows

```
s11polar = np.array(ena.query_ascii_values(cmdDict['s11']+cmdDict['polar']+';'+cmdDict['numGroups']+str(numGrps)+';outpform', separator='\n'))
```

But still, the same error has appeared.

I also change the code to the following version:

```
print(ena.query_ascii_values(cmdDict['s11']+cmdDict['polar']+';'+cmdDict['numGroups']+str(numGrps)+';outpform'), converter='s', separator='\n')
```

But still, the same error appears.

I would appreciate it if you please help me solve this error.

Comment: Are you opening a CSV?

Comment: No, I want to open an S2P.

Comment: You have two floats separated by a comma inside of a string you are trying to cast to float.  The result: Python is erroring out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So what should I do now? How can I modify it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That string does not represent one float number:

```
In [27]: astr = '   1.090393000000000E+00,  -2.059937000000000E-01'
In [28]: float(astr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [28] in <cell line: 1>
    float(astr)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '   1.090393000000000E+00,  -2.059937000000000E-01'
```

But we can split it into a list of strings that do convert:

```
In [29]: astr.split(',')
Out[29]: ['   1.090393000000000E+00', '  -2.059937000000000E-01']
In [30]: [float(x) for x in astr.split(',')]
Out[30]: [1.090393, -0.2059937]
```

and making an array from the list:

```
In [31]: np.array(_)
Out[31]: array([ 1.090393 , -0.2059937])
In [32]: np.array(astr.split(','), dtype=float)
Out[32]: array([ 1.090393 , -0.2059937])
```